VBA - Why does adding Custom tab to ribbon remove QAT
I have some vba code/XML that adds a new tab to my ribbon - but in doing so is removing any custom additions to the quick access toolbar - does anyone know why this is or how i can fix it?
Sub LoadCustRibbon()

Dim hFile As Long

Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String

Dim folderPath As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Debug.Print "Starting LoadCustRibbon routine."

' Get the file number

hFile = FreeFile

Debug.Print "FreeFile obtained: " & hFile

' Determine the correct folder path dynamically

folderPath = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Office\"

fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

Debug.Print "FolderPath constructed: " & folderPath

Debug.Print "Filename set: " & fileName

' Construct the ribbon XML

ribbonXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"" onLoad=""RibbonOnLoad"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<ribbon>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<tabs>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<tab id=""customTab"" label=""Trackit"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<group id=""group1"" label=""Matching"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<button id=""button1"" label=""Create/Update Baseline Match Sheet"" size=""large"" imageMso=""MacroPlay"" onAction=""CreateBaselineSheet""/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</group>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<group id=""group2"" label=""Calculations"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<button id=""button2"" label=""Push Calculations"" size=""large"" imageMso=""ShapeRightArrow"" onAction=""PushTheCalculations""/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</group>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<group id=""group3"" label=""Summary"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<button id=""button3"" label=""Generate Results Table"" size=""large"" imageMso=""TableInsert"" onAction=""MakeResults""/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</group>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<group id=""group4"" label=""Global Adjustments"">" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<button id=""button4"" label=""Add Inflation"" size=""large"" imageMso=""ShapeUpArrow"" onAction=""InflationCreation""/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "<button id=""button5"" label=""Apply Volume Normalisation"" size=""large"" imageMso=""QueryReturnGallery"" onAction=""VolumeCreation""/>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</group>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</tab>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</tabs>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</ribbon>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML & "</customUI>"

Debug.Print "Ribbon XML constructed: " & vbNewLine & ribbonXML

' Open file and write the XML

Debug.Print "Attempting to open file for output: " & folderPath & fileName

Open folderPath & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile

Debug.Print "File opened successfully."

Debug.Print "Writing ribbon XML to file."

Print #hFile, ribbonXML

Debug.Print "Closing file."

Close hFile

Debug.Print "LoadCustRibbon routine completed successfully."

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

If hFile <> 0 Then Close hFile

End Sub

This appears to insert the tab as expected but the quick access toolbar removes any custom elements and resets to default!

Looking into my own OfficeUI file, I see that there is a node <mso:qat> (with some sub nodes), and I assume that this defines the items in QAT. With your code, you overwrite the OfficeUI  file and this node is gone (and all other definitions in it also). You probably need to read in the file first to get the current content, then write the file, but add the nodes of the original file that you want to keep.
